# react native ios simulator no apps connected. sending reload to all react native apps failed

Tags: ios, react-native

As the title of the question says, it was working couple of days ago, but now, whatever I do, I get `warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.` especially when trying to run on iOS simulator. It works fine on android physical device, it is only on iOS simulator. My app just get stuck on splash screen and after that if I press r on metro bundler to reload, it throws this warning.

Note -> this happens with both `npx react-native run-ios` command and running with XCode.

What I have tried:

1. cleaning Pods cache, clean build, build again. (Didn't work).
2. reinstalling pods, build again. (Didn't work).
3. using different iOS simulator, same issue.
4. uninstalling, resinstalling app on simulator, didn't work.
5. Xcode scheme is set to "Debug" and not "release".
6. tried running `yarn start --reset-cache`. (Didn't work).

It is happening on all simulators (iOS only).

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "react": "18.0.0",
  "react-native": "0.69.2",
  ...,
},
```

What could go wrong? can someone shed some light?

Comment: This might be unrelated but i highly suggest that you upgrade to the latest patch react-native 0.69.5 or the latest version cause i remember having some issues with the version you are using currently.

Other than that, did you do any changes to your ios folder? if so please share

Comment: @RodSar yes, I did install `react-native-splash-screen` package & made some native code changes as per the documentation, but it was working after adding it too, and suddenly it stopped working...

Comment: @RodSar also, what is the safest way to upgrade to latest? I have heard updating react native to latest is a pain in the A, and it might break my whole project...

Comment: Seems like your app is launching on the native side but not using the react native bundle, you might wanna start investigating there, especially the changes you did on the native ios side

Comment: Yeah big updates are usually painful, but your upgrade should go smoothly as it's a relatively small update, after checking https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.69.2&to=0.69.5 it seems like the only step you need to do is upgrade your version in package.json and rebuild

Comment: @RodSar thanks! could you also please guide me how do I go about solving that issue? I'm new to iOS environemnt so... I tried everything that is related to this issue but couldn't solve it yet...

Comment: Sadly i won't be able to guide you step by step but your issue seems to be related to the splash screen package, so i'd research the issues and tips in their repo. good luck!

Comment: @RodSar turns out `react-native-splash-screen` was causing the problem indeed, right now I have removed the package cuz I couldn't identity the exact problem as there were only 2 changes which had to be done as per the documentation, removing those didn't work either...

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this issue after installing `react-native-splash-screen` the you might have placed `[RNSplashScreen show];` at the top or middle of the method.
You should place this `[RNSplashScreen show];` at the bottom of method before `return YES;`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm on react native 0.71.7 and this helped me bulid! I had spent more than 4 hours on just this one problem